# How can I get GPU usage / total on Android

Tags: java, android, gpu

Android version >= 8.0

I am creating an Android app based on Open GL ES 3.0

I want to get gpu info like memory/usage on Android in java

I have try

```c
bool m1 = GLEW_NVX_gpu_memory_info; // 0
bool m2 = glewIsSupported("GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info"); // 0
bool m3 = glewGetExtension("GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info"); // 0

GLint info = 0;

glGetIntegerv(GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX, @info);

GLenum err = glGetError();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    // error
}
```

but only for Nvidia